# How to return pointer adress for structure variable

Tags: c

I was working on data structures and while I was writing some code, I needed to return the address of the pointer that was defined in the structure. So here's my code but when I compile and run it, it doesn't work and give an error message as " assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast ". How should I rewrite it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
struct Node{
    
    int x;
    struct Node *next;
    
};


void main(){
    int i;
    struct Node *head;
    head = (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    head->next=NULL;
    
    
    /*Ekle(5,head);
    Ekle(10,head);
    Ekle(15,head);
    printf("Enter the value of 'ara' element");
    scanf("%d",&i);
    Print(head);
    ArayaEkle(i,20,head);
    Print(head);*/
    
    head = siraliEkle(10,head);
    head = siraliEkle(5,head);
    Print(head);
    
}

void Print(struct Node *root){
    
    while(root->next!=NULL){
        root = root->next;
        printf("%d\n",root->x);
        
        
    }
}

struct Node *siraliEkle(int sayi, struct Node *root){
    
    if(root==NULL){
        root = (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
        root->x = sayi;
        root->next = NULL;
        return root;
    }
    
    else if(root->next==NULL){
        if(root->x>sayi){
            struct Node *temp = (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
            temp->x = sayi;
            temp->next = root;
            root = temp;
            return root;
        }
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: Which line gives you the error? I get a lot of errors about implicit function declarations, since you declare your functions *after*  you use them

Comment: because *siraliEkle* is unknown in *main* the compiler supposes it returns an `int` and then `head = siraliEkle(10,head);` uses an `int` to initialize a pointer. Just move the functions definition before `main` or declare them before to use them

Comment: Since implementation was placed after the main function, I also get that warning but that's not a big issue I suppose. What I get as an error is that, when I try to compile and run the code, for the function of siraliEkle doesn't work. It must return the address of the root but it doesn't even start. It says conflicting type.

Comment: *"that's not a big issue I suppose."* - well you are wrong about that. You should treat all warnings as errors and fix them

Comment: I didn't mean that though. What I wanted to say was that, while I used to make some little projects, I used to define all the functions after the main function. Ofc when I come to the end, I search every little piece of the warnings and fix them. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @Mystheman you define the functions in the order you want, but it is needed to know their profile when they are called, that is all

Comment: Okay, I've just remembered that we need to define them as prototypes before the main function.

Answer (score 3):

You must **declare** (or define) functions before using them.

Without declaration nor definition, types of function arguments are assumed to `int` and it will cause trouble when actual types are not `int`.

```
struct Node{
    
    int x;
    struct Node *next;
    
};

/* add these declarations */
void Print(struct Node *root);
struct Node *siraliEkle(int sayi, struct Node *root);

int main(){ /* also return type should be standard int */
```

Also don't forget to return something from `siraliEkle` even if `root != NULL && (root->next != NULL || root->x <= sayi)`.

Comment: may be also warn the OP about the very strange definition of *Print* ? `while(root != NULL) { printf("%d\n",root->x); root = root->next; }` seems more appropriate

Comment: Thank you but I need to ask something. Can't we implement functions below the main function? I used to use my functions in that way when I created a little project with one of my friends and didn't have any error like this?

Comment: @Mystheman of course you can move them before *main* to avoid to declare them

Comment: Ohh okay,  I've just remembered, we used to define our functions with their types without any parameters before the main function. 
Like this:

'struct Node* siraliEkle();

void main()'

Comment: @Mystheman give the full profile when you declare them, the more you say the more the compiler can help you producing warning/error. The compiler does not produce warning/error *against* you but *for* you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return the address for the struct pointer use the declaration

```
struct Node *siraliEkle(int sayi, struct Node *root);
```

As below and return:

```
return &root;
```